# Execute command within current shell before every prompt

Tags: ksh, prompt

I'd like to have the current `jobs` status displayed in the title of my terminal. In Bash, I can use `PROMPT_COMMAND` for that. Korn Shell (ksh93) doesn't have that.

[Other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49925/how-to-set-the-commands-that-get-run-before-every-single-prompt) suggest using command substitution inside `$PS1`, which works fine in the general case, but not for the `jobs` command. The problem here is that `jobs` is concerned about the jobs of the *current shell*, but command substitution (i.e. `PS1='...$(jobs)...'`) is performed in a *subshell*, so there are no jobs.

The only mechanism I'm aware of is `trap '... jobs ...' DEBUG`, but that would execute way too often. Do you know a way how to run commands in the context of the current shell, once on each prompt, or is this not possible in Korn shell?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default if you just set `PS1="...."` then the stuff inside the quotes is evaluated at the time you set it.

However if you enclose it inside `'` instead then it's evaluated at display time.  And it doesn't cause a subshell for `$(jobs)`.

e.g.

```
$ PS1='
> $(jobs)
> $ '


$ sleep 1000 &
[1] 7541

[1] +  Running                 sleep 1000 &
$ sleep 1000 &
[2] 7543

[2] +  Running                 sleep 1000 &
[1] -  Running                 sleep 1000 &
$ kill %1
[1] - Terminated               sleep 1000 &

[2] +  Running                 sleep 1000 &
$ kill %2
[2] + Terminated               sleep 1000 &


$
```

(This test done on Debian Jessie with ksh93 but should work on all ksh93 variants; I don't have any ksh88 to test with.)

Comment: I was aware of the differences in evaluation, that wasn't the issue. But I was able to find my actual problem, once your answer confirmed that this should work without a subshell. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My actual problem was that (in contrast to the simplified example in my question), I actually massaged the `jobs` output in a function, separating running from stopped jobs.

This is my code for Bash:

```
typeset runningJobs=$(jobs -r | wc -l)
typeset stoppedJobs=$(jobs -s | wc -l)
```

which I ported to Korn shell in this way:

```
typeset runningJobs=$(jobs | grep -c ' Running ')
typeset stoppedJobs=$(jobs | grep -c ' Stopped ')
```

The *pipeline* inside the `$(...)` command substitution actually was causing `jobs` to be executed in a subshell (and therefore always yielded no output). By capturing the output in a variable, this can be prevented. The following rewrite works as expected:

```
typeset jobOutput=$(jobs)
typeset runningJobs=$(printf '%s\n' "$jobOutput" | grep -c ' Running ')
typeset stoppedJobs=$(printf '%s\n' "$jobOutput" | grep -c ' Stopped ')
```

<sup>Thanks to @StephenHarris for his answer, which helped me understanding the actual issue!</sup>

Comment: Beware oversimplification :-)

Comment: @StephenHarris: You don't want to see my huge (but critically important to me) mess of init scripts I've been building over 15+ years, starting first on HP-UX and various other Unixes :-)

Comment: I can't find the reference at the moment, but I think there's a special exception in the standard that says that if you run just a simple `jobs` command in a subshell, it will list the jobs in the parent shell.